# Pink/Purple Color with Java Resizer

Tags: java, grails, thumbnails

I'm using Groovy&Grails and thumbnailator to resize thumbnails with this lines of code:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("input.jpg"))
BufferedImage output = Thumbnails.of(image).size(400, 400).crop(Positions.CENTER).asBufferedImage()
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
ImageIO.write(output, "jpg", baos)
baos.flush()
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("output.jpg")
baos.writeTo(outputStream)
baos.close()
```

This works in 99% of all cases (same Java, OS, Sourcecode), with input.jpg. But in some non-reproducible cases, the image will become this:

[image: color]

I've checked other threads, such as the following link: 
[Pink/Reddish tint while resizing jpeg images using java thumbnailator or imgscalr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115851/pink-reddish-tint-while-resizing-jpeg-images-using-java-thumbnailator-or-imgscal)

I'm stuck with the situation that the exact same file works 99%, but in some, to be defined cases, doesn't.

My question: How can this behaviour be reproduced?

Answer (score 1):

Although the input is expected to be the same every time, something must be changing. What you can do is write out the input file unchanged along with `output.jpg`. When you encounter the problem then you'll be able to compare it's input file with the input file of a resize that have worked.

There should be some difference. If there is, then the problem is likely in the process providing the input file. If there isn't, which would be quite surprising, then something is wrong with the resizing code.

*TIP: You can use SHAx, MD5, etc to determine if the input files are different.*

## Confirming the input file

To confirm the input file, you can write the incoming data to a separate file.

```
def inputCopy = new FileOutputStream("input-SOMETHING-UNIQUE-HERE.jpg")
def input = new WritingInputStream(
    new FileInputStream("input.jpg"),
    inputCopy)

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input)
...
inputCopy.close()
```

The `WritingInputStream` writes data to an `OutputStream` as it's read from an `InputStream`. The source code is shown below:

```
class WritingInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    private OutputStream output

    public WritingInputStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) {
        super(input)

        this.output = output
    }

    int read() {
        int data = super.read()

        output.write(data)

        return data
    }

    int read(byte[] b) {
        int result = super.read(b)

        output.write(b)

        return result
    }

    int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
        int result = super.read(b, off, len)

        output.write(b, off, len)

        return result
    }    
}
```

An alternative to writing the `inputCopy` file out is to use an `ByteArrayOutputStream` and log the SHA1 of it's contents which you can then compare that to the SHA1 of the input file.

Comment: I had the purple-resizing output yesterday, given the source.jpg file that resulted in purple. I then deleted the output.jpg, restartet the tomcat instance and it worked. With the same input.jpg file, which sounds unbelievable but it is.

Comment: Is there an upload or something involved here? Where does the input come from?

Comment: Yes, the file is uploaded by the user and will be stored as original file in the filesystem. If I copy that file (ex. by Transmit) and upload it again, it will fail again. If I restart the Tomcat servlet and upload this very file again, it works.

Comment: That's good. Now it's not so unbelievable. It means the problem is likely between uploading the file and processing it. See my update about how to validate the input file.

Comment: Thank you for your update and effort. The strange thing is that it works with exactly the same file after a Tomcat restart.

Comment: It's the same input *file*, but probably not the same input. It won't be so strange once you figure out what's happening to the input file when it's loaded.

Comment: I too have a grails setup using thumbnailator for thumbnails, and I'm noticing the exact same behaviors. What's very strange is that it appears to get into a state where processing large files into thumbnails results in tinting, but smaller files get resized normally. I restarted tomcat once and the tint turned from pink to blue. It restarted overnight (due to a permgen) and now it appears to work perfectly. Did you ever get to the bottom of this @JohnSchmitz?

Comment: No I'm still fiddling with this. As soon as I restart the container, it works with larger files. It's still unsolved here.