# Convert Tif to JPEG cause wrong image colors

Tags: java, image, jai, image-conversion

I´m using JAI to convert a tiff file into ajpeg file, but when the file is converted the colors are totally wrong. What´s wrong with my code? Is this a JAI Bug? When converting to PNG the file colors are working fine.

```
try {
    FileSeekableStream stream = null;
    stream = new FileSeekableStream(tiff);
    ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", stream, null);
    RenderedImage image = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage(0);
    JAI.create("filestore", image, output, "JPEG");
    return true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

The output file:

[image]

The original file

[image]

Comment: Looks like your inverting the colors with the jpeg

Comment: Hi, How do this?

Comment: I invert with online app, but not the original colors are applied.

Comment: Be careful, ImageIO has a bug where writing a transparent image to a JPG causes issues in to the colors - see [Odd coloured JPEGs in Java with ImageIO](http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2009/04/odd-coloured-jpegs-in-java-with-imageio/) for more details

Comment: Possible duplicate [Pink/Reddish tint while resizing jpeg images using java thumbnailator or imgscalr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115851/pink-reddish-tint-while-resizing-jpeg-images-using-java-thumbnailator-or-imgscal) and [java buffered image created with red mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963685/java-buffered-image-created-with-red-mask)